# What is the equivalent code for the ASP.NET Core DI framework from this example using Ninject and .toconstant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ninject

I am migrating a project that used Ninject to another one that uses ASP.NET Core DI and I'm getting trouble when trying to inject this piece of code in Ninject:

```
Bind<PlayerService.PlayerServiceClient>()
                .ToConstant(new PlayerService.PlayerServiceClient(new Channel(Configuration.GetValue<string>("playerServiceEndpoint"), ChannelCredentials.Insecure)
                    .Intercept(new PrometheusClientInterceptor())));
```

How could I translate this?

Thanks you!

Comment: `ToConstant` sounds to me like `AsSingleton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I could make it work as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton(new PlayerService.PlayerServiceClient(new Channel(Configuration.GetValue<string>("playerServiceEndpoint"), ChannelCredentials.Insecure)));
```

Comment: why singilton not transit